# Favorites - How would I implement a favorites button so when it is pressed, the textView text is saved to an activity called favorites?

Tags: android, eclipse, favorites

I am creating an app with textView boxes. When a button is pressed the text changes using a random generator. How do I implement a favorite button so when it is pressed, a toast is created and the textView text is saved to an activity called favorites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would save the "textView" content as a `SharedPreference` in the `onClick()` method of the `Button`.

When the user accesses the Favorites Activity, I would send the `SharedPreference` value to the other Activity via the `Extras Bundle`

Depending on where you have to manage the list of stored Favorite values and how many there are, you may have to use a database instead of `SharedPreference`.

Answer (score 0):

For this what are `intents` made for...

say you want to send data from Activity A to B

1>then in A's oncreate() call this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,your.class);
i.putExtra("key", value);
startActivity(i);
```

2>and in B's oncreate() use this

```
int value = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key");
```

i guess you got what i meant...give it a try...